# key/value pair not incrementing

Tags: python, increment

I'm using the Head First Python 2nd edition.
I researched how to increment a key/value pair in dictionary but it's not working.

Using: Python 3.5.2. on Mac OS Sierra.

```
fruits = {} 
fruits['apples'] = 10
if 'bananas' in fruits:
    fruits['bananas'] += 1
else:
    fruits['bananas'] = 1
```

Initially when I print fruits it show bananas 1, apples 10 but the second time I print fruits it *should* show bananas 2 but doesn't. It still shows 1. Not increasing.

Comment: Data in the dictionary is not persistent after the program ends. If you run this in a for loop, you can observe the update.

Comment: You don't seem to be printing `fruits` at all.

Comment: If you put your code in a loop - make sure that the `fruits={}` isn't in the loop - as that code will create your dictionary from scratch again.

Comment: @DaniSpringer I'm not sure if adding the Python 3.x tag is warranted. This behaviour shouldn't be version-specific.

Comment: @Tagc true. ("3 more chars to go").

Comment: This short code fragment reinitializes `fruits` every time, so it's never going to get to the part that does the incrementing.

Comment: if you run if-else block again and again, it increments the fruit['banana'] value as expected. Hope you are not executing fruit = {} with if-else everytime.

Comment: It depends on what exactly  "initially" and "the second time" mean. The code you posted does not print anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is no loop for that if condition, may be you are running that program again which re-initializes 'fruits' dictionary again to an empty dictionary.